# android re-launching application as home button

Tags: android

After many hours of searching and reading articles I am not able to call my stopped application the same way as the home button is re-launching it. So I pressed home button and my application is stopped. And my service(from other package) can only start new instance of my application (main launching activity).

```
Context context = this.getBaseContext();
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
Intent appStartIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("main.application");
appStartIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
context.startActivity(appStartIntent);
```

If it is possible I would like to call onResume of my application from my service - I  didn't achieve it.

I try also this in my activity :D ...

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {  
    super.onStop();
    super.onResume():
}
```

The best unworking solution - override home button

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{       
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
```

Thank you very much for effort in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, don't do all that things! Please, read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html). The only way for you to achive the goal is to leverage Activity lifecycle callbacks to save/restore state.